# Performance cost when using RouteData.Values instead of querystring collection

Tags: asp.net, performance, query-string, url-routing

Would there be any noticeable performance cost when doing this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("key")
```

as opposed to this:

```
context.Request("key")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way, you're just accessing a collection. The RouteData.Values dictionary will be populated whether you use it or not, as will the Request.QueryString collection. There may be some overhead using Request("key") vs Request.QueryString("key"), as the former has to check the form collection as well, but it would beyond trivial, and I think the query string is checked first anyway.

Comment: 'beyond trivial'. Good enough for me.